# Program not performing the elif statement when balance equals bet

Tags: python

```
import random

print("Welcome to the Dice Game!")
Balance = int(input("How much money would you like to play with?:"))

Dice_again = "yes"

while Dice_again.casefold() == "y" or Dice_again.casefold() == "yes":
    Bet = int(input("How much would you like to bet?:"))
    if Bet > Balance:
        print("Sorry, you dont not have enough funds to bet this much.")
        print(f"You have ${Balance}.")
        continue
    elif Balance == 0:
        print("Sorry, you have $0 and cannot play the game anymore.")
        break
    Betnumber = int(input("What number would you like to bet on?:"))
    if Betnumber > 12:
        print("You have entered an invalid input.")
        continue
    Dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    Dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    Balance -= Bet
    Numberrolled = (Dice1 + Dice2)
    print("Now rolling....")
    while Balance >= Bet:
        if (Betnumber == 2) and (Numberrolled == 2):
            Winning1 = Bet * 36
            print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 2 and won ${Winning1}!")
            Balance += Winning1
            print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
            break
        elif (Betnumber == 3) and (Numberrolled == 3):
            Winning2 = Bet * 18
            print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 3 and won ${Winning2}!")
            Balance += Winning2
            print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
            break
        elif (Betnumber == 4) and (Numberrolled == 4):
            Winning3 = Bet * 12
            print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 4 and won ${Winning3}!")
            Balance += Winning3
            print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
            break
        elif (Betnumber == 5) and (Numberrolled == 5):
            Winning4 = Bet * 9
            print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 2 and won ${Winning4}!")
            Balance += Winning4
            print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
            break
        elif (Betnumber == 6) and (Numberrolled == 6):
            Winning5 = Bet * 7
            print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 2 and won ${Winning5}!")
            Balance += Winning5
            print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
            break
        elif (Betnumber == 7) and (Numberrolled == 7):
            Winning6 = Bet * 6
            print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 2 and won ${Winning6}!")
            Balance += Winning6
            print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
            break
        elif (Betnumber == 8) and (Numberrolled == 8):
            Winning7 = Bet * 7
            print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 2 and won ${Winning7}!")
            Balance += Winning7
            print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
            break
        elif (Betnumber == 9) and (Numberrolled == 9):
            Winning8 = Bet * 9
            print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 2 and won ${Winning8}!")
            Balance += Winning8
            print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
            break
        elif (Betnumber == 10) and (Numberrolled == 10):
            Winning9 = Bet * 12
            print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 2 and won ${Winning9}!")
            Balance += Winning9
            print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
            break
        elif (Betnumber == 11) and (Numberrolled == 11):
            Winning10 = Bet * 18
            print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 2 and won ${Winning10}!")
            Balance += Winning10
            print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
            break
        elif (Betnumber == 12) and (Numberrolled == 12):
            Winning11 = Bet * 36
            print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 2 and won ${Winning11}!")
            Balance += Winning11
            print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
            break
        else:
            print(f"Sorry, but you rolled a {Numberrolled}.")
            print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
            break

    Dice_again = input("Would you like to play again (N/Y)?")
    if Dice_again.casefold() == "yes" or Dice_again.casefold() == "y":
        continue
    elif Dice_again.casefold() == "no" or Dice_again.casefold() == "n":
        print(f"You have stopped the game with ${Balance} in your hand.")
        break
    else:
        print("You have entered an invalid input.")
        break
```

Whenever I run the program and the bet value equals the balance, it doesn't display the else statement I have it set to display but instead, it goes down the program and outputs the other information that is supposed to be outputted later on.

Here's an example of what happens when the bet doesn't equal the balance and when they equal each other:

```
Welcome to the Dice Game!
How much money would you like to play with?:100
How much would you like to bet?:50
What number would you like to bet on?:12
Now rolling....
Sorry, but you rolled a 7.
You now have $50.
Would you like to play again (N/Y)?yes
How much would you like to bet?:50
What number would you like to bet on?:12
Now rolling....
Would you like to play again (N/Y)?
```

Comment: You subtract the bet from the balance. After that the condition of the while-loop may not be met anymore. E. g. if you have 50 and bet 50 the balance goes to 0 and is less than the bet.

Comment: The scoring shouldn't be in a while loop at all, because you only want to do it once per bet

Comment: You shouldn't subtract the bet from the balance until after the player rolls a number that doesn't match.

Comment: Unrelated, but this would allow a player to make a negative bet with a negative bankroll. `Balance > 0` should be a loop invariant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like people said in comments. The issue you have is this

```
Balance -= Bet
...
while Balance >= Bet:
    # do rest
```

So when you have `Bet` equal to `Balance` then it subtracts it and the condition is no longer valid. What you want is to move subtraction inside of `while` loop

```
...
while Balance >= Bet:
    Balance -= Bet
    # do rest
```

Another issue I notices is that you have two whiles loops, and second loop will always runs once. So there is no reason to even have it, it would make sense to replace it with `if` statement and remove `break` inside of `if` statements that are inside of this `while` loop.

**Edited**:
Answer to Author's question in the comment. You replace make second `while` an `if`:

```
if Balance >= Bet:
    Balance -= Bet
    if (Betnumber == 2) and (Numberrolled == 2):
        Winning1 = Bet * 36
        print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 2 and won ${Winning1}!")
        Balance += Winning1
        print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
    elif (Betnumber == 3) and (Numberrolled == 3):
        Winning2 = Bet * 18
        print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 3 and won ${Winning2}!")
        Balance += Winning2
        print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
    elif (Betnumber == 4) and (Numberrolled == 4):
        Winning3 = Bet * 12
        print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 4 and won ${Winning3}!")
        Balance += Winning3
        print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
    elif (Betnumber == 5) and (Numberrolled == 5):
        Winning4 = Bet * 9
        print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 2 and won ${Winning4}!")
        Balance += Winning4
        print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
    elif (Betnumber == 6) and (Numberrolled == 6):
        Winning5 = Bet * 7
        print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 2 and won ${Winning5}!")
        Balance += Winning5
        print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
    elif (Betnumber == 7) and (Numberrolled == 7):
        Winning6 = Bet * 6
        print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 2 and won ${Winning6}!")
        Balance += Winning6
        print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
        break
    elif (Betnumber == 8) and (Numberrolled == 8):
        Winning7 = Bet * 7
        print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 2 and won ${Winning7}!")
        Balance += Winning7
        print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
    elif (Betnumber == 9) and (Numberrolled == 9):
        Winning8 = Bet * 9
        print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 2 and won ${Winning8}!")
        Balance += Winning8
        print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
        break
    elif (Betnumber == 10) and (Numberrolled == 10):
        Winning9 = Bet * 12
        print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 2 and won ${Winning9}!")
        Balance += Winning9
        print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
    elif (Betnumber == 11) and (Numberrolled == 11):
        Winning10 = Bet * 18
        print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 2 and won ${Winning10}!")
        Balance += Winning10
        print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
        break
    elif (Betnumber == 12) and (Numberrolled == 12):
        Winning11 = Bet * 36
        print(f"Congratulations! You rolled a 2 and won ${Winning11}!")
        Balance += Winning11
        print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
    else:
        print(f"Sorry, but you rolled a {Numberrolled}.")
        print(f"You now have ${Balance}.")
```

Comment: If I remove the second if statement than how would it loop back up when the user is asked if they would like to play again? And thank you for your help.